# How to use a map of tuples with Boost?

Tags: c++, boost

Trying to map ids to tuples containing arbitrary data:

```
typedef boost::tuples::tuple<std::string, std::string, unsigned char> data;
typedef std::map<uint64, data> data_map;

const data_map DATA = boost::assign::map_list_of
        (0, boost::tuples::make_tuple("XXX", "xxx", 0))
        (0, boost::tuples::make_tuple("YYY", "yyy", 1))
        (0, boost::tuples::make_tuple("ZZZ", "zzz", 2))
```

How can I access the tuples in the DATA map? I am trying with:

```
data_map::const_iterator itData = DATA.find(id);
```

But then accessing it (after checking if found) with:

```
data metadata = itData->second;
```

Throws an error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'boost::tuples::cons<const char (&)[12], boost::tuples::cons<int, boost::tuples::null_type> >::stored_head_type {aka const char (&)[12]}' from expression of type 'const char [11]'
```

Comment: Are you sure it's that line that causes the error? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: When I replaced the `boost::tuples::make_tuple` call with creating the `data` tuple directly solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, that makes much more sense than what you said in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When replacing `boost::tuples::make_tuple` with creating the `data` tuple directly worked:

```
typedef boost::tuples::tuple<std::string, std::string, unsigned char> data;

const data_map DATA = boost::assign::map_list_of
        (0, data("XXX", "xxx", 0))
        (1, data("YYY", "yyy", 1))
        (2, data("ZZZ", "zzz", 2))
```

Answer (score 4):

Engaging my crystal ball:

I think you have used `decltype(obj)` where object was the result of `std::make_tuple("abcdefghijk",...)` or `std::tie("abcdefghij",...)`.

This is because the error message talks about this type of tuple element (`const char (&)[12]`).

---

Demonstration that the above code is fine:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eed2c9d391801b72)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <map>

typedef boost::tuples::tuple<std::string, std::string, unsigned char> data;
typedef std::map<uint64_t, data> data_map;

int main() {

    const data_map DATA = boost::assign::map_list_of
            (0, boost::tuples::make_tuple("XXX", "xxx", 0))
            (1, boost::tuples::make_tuple("YYY", "yyy", 1))
            (2, boost::tuples::make_tuple("ZZZ", "zzz", 2));


    data_map::const_iterator itData = DATA.find(2);
    data metadata = itData->second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
string("xxx")
```

Instead of:

```
"xxx"
```

for each string you have inside make_tuple calls.